# XNA Find point position after a transform

Tags: xna, rotation

I assumed this was a straightforward problem but it has been plaguing me for days.

My problem is: find a vertex position of a model after applying some transformation in worlds coordinates.

I try to be more clearer: I have one simple model that I rotate. I can't find the positon of this model in the world. For example if I take the bounding sphere position, it does't change after the rotation.

I very much appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're asking how to determine the world-space position of a single 3 dimensional vector after having been transformed by a world-matrix.

Assuming you have the position of the model, and the world matrix you're transforming the model by, you can use the following method to transform a single Vector3 into world space.

```
var worldMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationZ(...);
var modelSpacePosition = new Vector3(...);

var worldSpacePosition = Vector3.Transform(modelSpacePosition, worldMatrix);
```

Comment: Let me try to explain better: I have a model with some bones, when I rotate the root bone also rotate all the child bones.
Now what i

Comment: Let me try to explain better: I have a model with some bones, when I rotate the root bone also rotate all the child bones.
Now, what I want, is to retrive the position of a single point of a child after the rotation. The problem is they don't change after the rotation, they have the same coordinates as before rotation.
My world matrix is the identity. There is a easy way to get the coordinates after the rotation or I have to multiply the coordinates of the point for the matrix transformation applied to the root bone?